# DC output through PSU not readable by a multimeter

Tags: power-supply

I am using [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XPRZ1YJ) 300w 12v PSU for small pool/spa set up. It powers LED bulbs fine but the problem is that I am never able to get reading with multimeter (no DC reading from this particular PSU - the multimeter is working fine for anything else).

Now, I tried to connect the [LED strip light that comes with a little control box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TSKLQSQ) (that remote "talks" to and the control box is able to change colors, etc.) with no success. I can connect the LED strip directly (bypassing its controller) and it lights up fine. I can also connect the LED strip along with the controller to its original 12v PSU and it works fine.

So, the problem is between the LED controller box and my PSU - it must have the same issue of not able to "accept" the DC signal from this particular PSU as my multimeter does.

Is it possible that the DC signal from the PSU is not "clean" enough and this is messing up my multimeter and the LED controller box? Is there a way to verify and address the issue?

Thank you

Comment: Transformers produce AC, not DC.  What you need is a power supply, not a transformer.

Comment: Thanks. I just used the manufacturer language but it’s actually PSU and you can see the details in the link. I changed the language accordingly.

Comment: The product description on your link clearly states that the device is a transformer that outputs 12, 13, or 14 volts AC.  If you set your meter to read AC Volts, you should be able to measure those voltages.  The information on the LED strips and controller states that they require 12 volts DC, so they won't work with the transformer.  (The LED strips may work on AC when the polaritiy is right - they'd be dimmer than normal, I think)

Answer (score 2):

Transformers produce AC, not DC, and you've linked a 12v AC transformer. Switch your multimeter to AC and you should be able to measure the voltage.

Your equipment needs DC, so you should get a 12v power supply.

Comment: This is an embarrassing operator error. Thank you all.

Comment: @mvoltin also you might have damaged the control box by feeding it AC. Might. It could still be okay.